# What type of chart would be best for displaying this data?

Tags: presentation

[image]

**EDIT:**
I don't mean in terms of how to implement it. i mean i dont like how the date is displayed with the bars. what other type of chart would be more suitable. I know a threadhold line wouldnt work beacause the values of the capacity are different for each day. if they were all the same a threadhold line indicating capacity would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a line graph would be an excellent way to show the data.

[image]

I made that using the [chart wizard.](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/chart_wizard.html) Link: [here](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=440x220&cht=lxy&chco=3072F3,FF0000&chds=0,20,0,20,0,20,0,20&chd=t:-1|9,11,5,10,16,17,13|-1|7,14,7,5,12,9,14&chdl=Capacity|Demand&chdlp=b&chls=2,4,1|1&chma=5,5,5,25&chtt=Total+Capacity+vs+Demand). I used the data you provided above, so it should be accurate unless I mistyped.

On the chart wizard, you can import this chart using the link I gave you above if you want to clean it up, add axes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is impossible to answer, depends on too many things specially since you didn't clarify almost anything in you question.

Anyway, [Google's chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/making_charts.html) would be ans **"easy"** way to do this.

Good luck, I you clarify further in your question, I'll try to be more specific and improve my answer!

It can do this quite easily:

[image]

[See here.](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/bar_charts.html#series_colors)